Conditional Form rendering in Ionic Angular
I'm trying to use the same component to edit some info with two different classes, is there a way to make it work?
component:
@Component({
  selector: 'live-care-monorepo-editutente',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './editutente.component.html',
  styleUrl: './editutente.component.css',
})
export class EditutenteComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() user!: UtenteDTO | OperatoreDTO;
    @Input() userType: string;

    constructor(
        private modalController: ModalController,
        public UtentiService: UtentiService,
        public OperatoriService: OperatoriService,
        public CheckTipo: TypeCheckService
        ) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.userType === 'operatore') {
            console.log("operatore")
            this.user as OperatoreDTO;
        } else if (this.userType === 'utente') {
            console.log("utente")
            this.user as UtenteDTO;
        } else {
            // Handle other types or undefined
            console.error('Unsupported user type');
        }
    }
    dismissModal() {
        this.modalController.dismiss();
    }

    saveUser() {
        if (this.userType === 'utente') {
            const utente = this.user as UtenteDTO;
            if (utente.Nome && utente.Cognome && utente.Cellulare && utente.Email) {
                this.UtentiService.ModificaUtente(utente);
                this.dismissModal();
            } else {
                alert('Riempire tutti i campi');
            }
        } else if (this.userType === 'operatore') {
            const operatore = this.user as OperatoreDTO;
            if (operatore.Utente.Nome && operatore.Utente.Cognome && operatore.Utente.Cellulare && operatore.Utente.Email){
                this.UtentiService.ModificaUtente(operatore.Utente);
                this.OperatoriService.ModificaOperatore(operatore);
                this.dismissModal();
            } else {
                alert('Riempire tutti i campi');
            }
        } else if (this.CheckTipo.isPazienteDTO(this.user)) {
            const paziente = this.user as PazienteDTO;
            
        }
    }
}

Template:
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ng-container *ngIf="CheckTipo.isUtenteDTO(user)">
            <ion-title>Modifica Utente</ion-title>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="CheckTipo.isOperatoreDTO(user)">
            <ion-title>Modifica Operatore</ion-title>
        </ng-container>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-button (click)="dismissModal()">Chiudi</ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content *ngIf="CheckTipo.isUtenteDTO(user)">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item >
            <ion-label position="stacked">Nome</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngModel]="user.Nome"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Cognome</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.Cognome"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Numero di Telefono</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="user.Cellulare" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.Email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-button class="btn-anagrafica" (click)="saveUser()">Salva</ion-button>
</ion-content>

<ion-content *ngIf="CheckTipo.isOperatoreDTO(user)">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Nome</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngModel]="user.Utente.Nome"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Cognome</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.Utente.Cognome"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Numero di Telefono</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="user.Utente.Cellulare" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.Utente.Email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-button class="btn-anagrafica" (click)="saveUser()">Salva</ion-button>
</ion-content>

TypeCheck Service:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TypeCheckService {

  constructor() { }
    public isUtenteDTO(user: any): user is UtenteDTO {
        return user;
    }

    public isOperatoreDTO(user: any): user is OperatoreDTO {
        return user;
    }

    public isPazienteDTO(user: any): user is PazienteDTO {
        return user;
    }

    public isUtenteDTONew(user: any): user is UtenteDTONew{
        return user;
    }

    public isOperatoreDTONew(user: any): user is OperatoreDTONew{
        return user;
    }
}

Example of the info passed to the component (which is used which path to follow when calling the saveUser function):
async editDettagliUtente(user: UtenteDTO) {
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
            component: EditutenteComponent,
            componentProps: {
                user: user,
                userType: 'utente'
            }
        });

        return await modal.present();
    }

I tried using the typecheck service to pick which ion-content block to show, but they both show when the component is called, maybe due to the typing of @Input user, but i don't see other ways to follow

Typescript is for adding types to help the end user code, it's not for checking conditionals on html, since when it gets converted to javascript in the browser, the type checking will not work! instead go for conditionals based on actual data (user)
Typescript might work in some cases and for some cases it won't for a reliable solution go for actual data conditional instead of conditionals based on the type!
public isUtenteDTO(user: any): user is UtenteDTO {
    return this.userType === 'utente';
}

public isOperatoreDTO(user: any): user is OperatoreDTO {
    return this.userType === 'operatore';
}

public isPazienteDTO(user: any): user is PazienteDTO {
    return this.userType !== 'utente';
}

public isUtenteDTONew(user: any): user is UtenteDTONew{
    // not sure what is the conditional for this, but I hope you get the picture!
    return user;
}

public isOperatoreDTONew(user: any): user is OperatoreDTONew{
    // not sure what is the conditional for this, but I hope you get the picture!
    return user;
}

